# win32 using while loop with ReadFile/WriteFile in C to write from one program to a new one

Tags: winapi, file-io, while-loop

I've written a program that reads text from one file and copies it to a new file. Using a while loop and the ReadFile/Writefile functions, my program works...but my program won't stop running unless I force stop it. I'm guessing that I'm not closing my handles properly or that my while loop may be set up wrong. Once I force stop my program, the file is successfully copied over to the new location with a new name.

```
int n = 0;
while(n=ReadFile(hFileSource, buffer, 23, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
    WriteFile(hFileNew, buffer, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
}       

CloseHandle(hFileSource);
CloseHandle(hFileNew);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not correctly testing for the end-of-file. `ReadFile` doesn't return failure for EOF, it returns success but with 0 bytes read. To correctly check for EOF:

```
while (ReadFile(hFileSource, buffer, 23, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
{
    if (dwBytesRead == 0)
        break;
    // write data etc
}
```

Is there any reason you're only reading/writing 23 bytes at a time? This will be rather inefficient.

Comment: I would opt to change the loop into a `do/while` and move the `ReadFile()` call inside of the loop so that it can do error handling on `ReadFile()` and report any read errors and discard the incomplete destination file if the source file cannot be read file correctly. Otherwise, you have to check for an error after the loop exits, but then you don't know if it was `ReadFile()` or `WriteFile()` that errored.